# Problems installing PHP 5.4.11 and MySQL 5.6.10 on CentOS 6.3

Tags: php, mysql, linux, installation, centos

I'm attempting to install **PHP 5.4.11** and **MySQL 5.6.10** onto a **CentOS 6.3** box.

I've successfully installed PHP 5.4.11 via the remi repository for yum. I've also successfully installed MySQL 5.6.10 using the community server rpm's on the [MySQL downloads page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.6.html).

They both work fine independently, but when attempting to install `php-mysql` from the remi repository, a dependency of `mysql-libs` is pulled in which is at version 5.5.30, and going ahead with the install produces an array of errors like the following:

```
file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-libs-5.5.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MySQL-server-5.6.10-1.el6.x86_64
```

At this point, I'm out of my depth with regards to getting this working. Can anyone suggest what I need to do to get my PHP installation working with MySQL?

Comment: You might have better luck getting this answered at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @BennyHill Thanks for the tip, I've just [added it to ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/480321/problems-installing-php-5-4-11-and-mysql-5-6-10-on-centos-6-3) as well.

Answer (score -1):

rpm --nodeps --force

just override

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on your answer to make it more understandable.

Comment: I don't fully understand this answer. Regardless, I can see that yum [doesn't support](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/NoDeps) `--nodeps`, and that's what I'd be using to add it, like so: `yum install php-mysql`.